# Use of <To do this>

Tags: sentence-construction

Is the use of "To do this" in the following sentences correct grammatically and conceptually? If it is not , kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

A series of engineering techniques to reduce the thermal conductivity of nanoscale channels are investigated. **To do this**, Zhu et al. [2] investigated phonon conduction on two dimensional graphene/boron nitride super lattices in different periods and interface structures which can be used to produce thermoelectricity.

Comment: It isn't wrong, but it seems unnecessary. Why do you want to add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. It's important that *this* is near what it references to avoid confusion, which in this case it is (the investigation).

I think the *to do the investigation, they investigated* idea could be rewritten as something like this:

> Zhu et al. **investigated** a series of engineering techniques that reduce thermal conductivity of nanoscale channels **using** phonon conduction on two-dimensional graphene/boron nitride super lattices in different periods and interface structures that produce thermoelectricity.